# CoreData to store the server content

Tags: json

I have a very specific question. I have the requirements to read the data from server (JSON format), store in Core Data and then update the UI (tables) by reading the data from Core Data. The reason I need to store the data in Core Data because I have a requirement to show the data offline (When there is no network).

So what I am doing is this:

Read the JSON from the server, create the Managed Object Entities and store in Core Data.

Upon success of save of Core Data, send the event to View Controller which then will read the data from Core Data.

The question is:
Can/Should view controller use the Managed Object Entity directly that are returned by Core Data OR should I create the custom Entities that are consumed by UIViewController?

What should be the strategy if the entity is not found in Core Data then I need to go to server again to get it and store in Core Data.

In general this is a very common scenario and I am seeking the experts advise how to go about designing it?

Thanks in advance!